# Suppress Valgrind when Memory Location is Unknown

Tags: valgrind

I am trying to add code in a Valgrind suppression file that removes errors and warnings that do not list the actual function calls or files causing the errors and warnings.

For instance:

```
 <b>IPW</b> ==55555== Invalid write of size X
 ==55556==      at  0xFFFFFFFF: ???
 ==55557==      by 0xFFFFEEEE: ???
```

Therefore I am trying to create a few lines of code in a Valgrind suppression file that will suppress all of these instances where the function call or file causing the error/warning is unknown. Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the Valgrind docs that explain how to do this. Does anyone know how to suppress errors or warnings coming from unknown function calls or file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify that your changes aren't causing the issue and it's really an issue/false-positive within outside code.

If so, you can add the following line into your Valgrind suppression to get what you need:

```
obj:???
```